# How to set character limit in Text field ..?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

My py and xml files code show below and 
i want to set 300 character limit for text field so what kind of changes needed in this code ?

.py Code :

`description': fields.text('Description', required=True)`

.Xml Code :

```
<field name="description"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am explaining how to use constraints effectively.

```
@api.constrains('your_field')
@api.one
def _check_your_field(self):

    if len(self.your_field) > 300:
        raise ValidationError('Number of characters must not exceed 300')
```

Don't forget to import

```py
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
```

Answer (score 4):

**You May Have To Set The size Attribute on Field Level**

```
description': fields.text('Description', required=True,size=150)
```

Odoo automatically adjusts the size based on your configurated size attribute on the field level.

Hear no need to required to set any kind of size from the XML part .

**Field Attriute: size=150**

it means that users will not able to add the more then 150 characters into that description field

I hope my answer may help you.

Comment: I think you have not upgraded that module properly or if it was upgraded well then try to uninstall that module and install it again so that you will get the expected result

Comment: `Text` field type does not support `size` attribute. Tested on version 12.0 (maybe it was working on older versions?). Instead you can use `Char` field type, but then add `widget="text"` on field in xml, to have Text field interface, but keep `Char` behavior.